# Non reproducible problem

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, unanswered-questions

I asked yesterday a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147240/pdf-output-showing-blank-spaces-instead-of-math) about a problem I encountered. However the problem was in someone else's computer that I have very limited access to and the problem went away after a recompilation. It is really mysterious and I have seen similar behavior before, so when I asked the question I assumed somebody would quickly recognize it as a common issue.

It turns out it is not so common. So I do not see how a normal person can answer my own question, since I admit that I cannot provide sufficient data to the readers.

Is it better to leave all as it is and wait until someone who encountered the exact same problem writes an answer, or mark the question for deletion?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suggest, to not delete the question, and to not let it remain open, since it's hardly answerable, but to close it.

So people, who might encounter the same problem, could find your question via google or another search engine and could comment or edit and extend your question. Also if they would know a solution, they can vote to reopen the question or at least comment to it at first.

You could post a comment to that question (perhaps link to here) and vote to close.